# Как получить доступ к созданному объекту из другого класса?

Tags: java, классы, ссылки

Всем доброго дня!
Модель: MVC

Создано 4 класса: `Main, Model, Controller, Viewer`
Я хочу в классе Model вызвать метод класса `Controller.showMessage()`;
Но почему-то в классе `Model` я не могу обращаться и видеть класс `Controller`.
Код ниже:

```
<br>
Main.java<br>
public class Main {<br>
    public static void main(String[] args) {<br>
        Viewer viewer = new Viewer();<br>
        viewer.connectToModel();<br>
        viewer.model.showMessage();<br>
    }<br>
}

public class Viewer {
    Controller controller;
    Model model;

    Viewer () {
        controller = new Controller(this);
    }

    void connectToModel() {
        this.model = controller.model;
        System.out.println("SUCCES! Connection is completed! The reference is created");
    }

}
public class Controller {
    Viewer v;
    Model model;

    Controller (Viewer v) {
        this.v = v;
        model = new Model(v, this);
    }
    void showMessage() {
        System.out.println("Controller");
    }
}

public class Model {
    Viewer v;
    Controller controller;

    Model (Viewer v, Controller controller) {
        this.v = v;
        this.controller = controller;
    }


    void showMessage() {
        System.out.println("HELLO FROM MODEL");
    }
}
```

Как мне вызвать метод `"showMessage"` в классе `Controller` из класса `Model`? Объекты уже созданы, второй объект класса Controller создавать не нужно.

Заранее спасибо товарищи!

Comment: Разобрался! Я пытался вызвать метод в КЛАССЕ, а нужно его вызывать в МЕТОДЕ класса или конструктора.

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы, все *просто*!

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Viewer viewer = new Viewer();
            viewer.connectToModel();
            viewer.showMessage();       // Вызывать метод у самого обьекта, а не у его представления.
        }
    }
```